# Google Cloud DNS with mailgun

Tags: mailgun, spf, google-cloud-dns

I have one domain with Google Cloud DNS. My SPF record doesn't work with mailgun domain verification

v=spf1 include:spf.protection.outlook.com include:_spf.google.com include:mailgun.org ~all

anyone facing the same issue?

thanks

Answer (score 21):

In case anyone need answer here's how i fixed it

via Google cloud control panel i added opening and closing quote to TXT spf record

"v=spf1 include:spf.protection.outlook.com include:_spf.google.com include:mailgun.org ~all"

thanks

Comment: txt records need quotes around the text string, which is done automatically by Cloud DNS so that the values you input conform to DNS syntax. However, Cloud DNS is also set up to strip any whitespace in txt records. That's why it transformed your oneliner into multiple strings, and you had to add the quotes around the whole record manually.